# Gulp injecting can not inject multiple bundle but file is created

Tags: angular, gulp, inject

Gulp inject is not injecting multiple js bundle in index.html. I am using angular project and gulp  to manage the project. while I am injecting file. only one file is injected as a bundle. I need to inject too many bundle atleast 5 bundles. because the project volume and script file is huge.

```
var corebundle = gulp.src([path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.module.js')]
,{allowEmpty: true,buffer:true,sourcemaps:true,nounique:false})
.pipe(concat('corebundle.js')).
pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')));

var mainbundle = gulp.src([
    path.join(conf.paths.src, '/app/**/*.js')
],{ allowEmpty: true,buffer:true,sourcemaps:true,nounique:false})
.pipe(concat('mainbundle.js'))
.pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')));

***The below code I ran for injecting***
return gulp.src(path.join(conf.paths.src, '/*.html'))
    .pipe($.inject(injectStyles, injectOptions))
    .pipe($.inject(corebundle, injectOptions)) // js bundle can add
    .pipe($.inject(mainbundle, injectOptions)) // js bundle can not add
    .pipe(wiredep(_.extend({}, conf.wiredep)))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve')));
```